# How to open one file as "read only" but the others as writable using command line?

Tags: command-line

Here is what I am doing now:

```
vim + $1 -c "set titlestring=$title guioptions-=m guioptions-=r lines=66 columns=239" -c ":source .vim_map" -c "sp .help.txt" -c ":wincmd j"
```

I would like to open the **.help.txt** in split window but as *read-only* where the other file (the $1 as it is in the script) to be writable.

How can I do this?

Regards,
Piotr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:sview`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Asview) command, which opens the file in a split and sets `'readonly'` on it.

```
vim ... -c "sview .help.txt" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. First split the window, then view the file.

Replace this `-c "sp .help.txt"` with this `-c "sp" -c "view .help.txt"`